# vb.net Button Text with the & hot key

Tags: vb.net

I have a button on a form and am using the & before a character in the text property to make it a hot key accessible with the ctrl key.  My problem is that when I start the program, the underline does not appear until the user presses the ctrl key.  How do I make the underline display when the program starts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows doesn't show the underline until the user presses the Alt key. It's standard Windows behaviour. Try pressing Alt-F in Notepad and look at the File menu caption. The user can change this behaviour in their Windows settings. I think it's best to respect the normal Windows behaviour.